# Sliding tiles solver in Python

Tags: python, sliding-tile-puzzle

I've implemented the sliding blocks puzzle in Python to solve it using different algorithms.
I'd like to know if the class "Sliding_blocks" is nicely designed or if I am missing 
concepts of OOP.

I think that the indices of the blocks are a bit obfuscated, because I mix tuples,
lists and arrays (arrays are better to add but then I have to convert them to tuples 
at some point).

I use the A* algorithm with the number of misplaced blocks as heuristic function.
It's quite slow and I think's it's because I have to create many copies of objects.

I'm more concerned with best practices than speed.

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from copy import copy, deepcopy


class Sliding_blocks():

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 4
        self.block = self.generate_block()


    def generate_block(self):
        """Goal state"""

        block = np.arange(1,self.size**2)
        block.resize(self.size,self.size)
        return block


    def move(self, piece):
        """Moves the piece with index "piece" to free place, if possible"""

        if list(piece) in self.find_moves():
            self.block[tuple( self.find_free() )] = self.block[tuple(piece)]
            self.block[tuple(piece)] = 0
            return "success"
        else:
            return "error"


    def find_free(self):
        """Returns array of indices of the free cell"""

        free_position = np.where(self.block == 0)
        free_position = np.array(free_position).flatten()
        return free_position


    def find_moves(self):
        """Returns list of allowed indices to move"""

        from itertools import product
        free_position = self.find_free()
        return [list(free_position+i) for i in [[0,1],[1,0],[-1,0],[0,-1]] if tuple(i+free_position) in product(range(self.size),repeat=2)]


    def shuffle(self):
        steps = 30
        for i in xrange(steps):
            self.rand_move()


    def rand_move(self):
        from random import choice

        self.move(choice(self.find_moves()))


    #The following functions are used to find the solution

    def isWin(self):
        return (self.block == self.generate_block()).all()


    def total_misplaced(self):
        return np.sum( self.block != self.generate_block() )


def tree_search():#
    Game = Sliding_blocks()
    Game.shuffle()

    frontier = [[Game]]
    explored = []

    while 1:
        if frontier==[]: return "Error"

        path, frontier = remove_choice(frontier)
        endnode = path[-1]
        explored.append(endnode)
        if endnode.isWin(): return path

        #Iterate over all possible actions at endnode
        for action in allactions(endnode):
            if not action in explored and not action in frontier or action.isWin():
                pathtem=copy(path)
                pathtem.append(action)
                frontier.append(pathtem)


def allactions(obj):
    possible = obj.find_moves()
    actions = []
    for i in range(len(possible)): 
        actions.append(deepcopy(obj))
        actions[i].move(possible[i])
    return actions


#A*
def a_star(frontier):
    #Calculates the cost (lenght + number misplaced cells)
    #of all paths in frontier, returns the frontier
    #without the least expensive path and also returns that path

    lengths = [f[-1].total_misplaced()+cost(f) for f in frontier]
    shortest=[i for i,l in enumerate(lengths) if l<=min(lengths)]
    return frontier.pop(shortest[0]), frontier 



def cost(path): return len(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    remove_choice = a_star
    sol = tree_search()
    for s in sol: 
        print s.block
        print "\n"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review! This is a good first question and I hope you receive great answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the code is well designed or not -- is hard to tell without using it. But I have several points:

1. It's good that you have small functions/methods which do one thing and do well. It's good that you wrote docstrings and comments.
2. `shortest=[i for i,l in enumerate(lengths) if l<=min(lengths)]` -- here you are calculating `min(lengths)` on each loop cycle. Calculate this and put into a variable.
3. Comply with PEP-8. `def cost(path): return len(path)` -> have two different lines. `np.arange(1,self.size**2)` use one space after commas. `Game = Sliding_blocks()` -- only classes should named CamelCased -> `game = SlidingBlocks()`. Use `pylint` to see all warnings.
4. Use `enumerate`:

   ```
   for i in range(len(possible)): 
       actions.append(deepcopy(obj))
       actions[i].move(possible[i])
   ```

Will become:

```
    for i, _possible in enumerate(possible): 
        action = deepcopy(obj)
        actions.append(action)
        action.move(_possible)
```

5. Move the imports to the top of the file

   ```
   def rand_move(self):
       from random import choice
   ```
6. Import module instead of objects from it.

   ```
   from itertools import product
   ...
   from random import choice
   ```

Will become:

```
import copy
import itertools
import random
```

7. Using constants? Name them uppercase and make global. Is it a setting? Pass it as an argument with a default value or store as a class attribute.

   ```
   def shuffle(self):
       steps = 30
       for i in xrange(steps):
           self.rand_move()
   ```
8. Fail early.

   ```
       if list(piece) in self.find_moves():
           self.block[tuple( self.find_free() )] = self.block[tuple(piece)]
           self.block[tuple(piece)] = 0
           return "success"
       else:
           return "error"
   ```

This can be rewritten as

```
        if list(piece) not in self.find_moves():
            return "error"
        ...
        return "success"
```

This will also reduce indentation.

`return "error"` -- this is a hardcoded string. Use a constant.

9. Indeed, using `tuple`s and `list`s is hard to read and is slow

   ```
   if list(piece) in self.find_moves():
       self.block[tuple( self.find_free() )] = self.block[tuple(piece)]
       self.block[tuple(piece)] = 0
   ```

You should rethink this.